# Prove that in a group iterated commutators with repeated generators is trivial implies that each generator commutes with all its conjugates

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group with generating set $S=\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$. Let $[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$ be the commutator of $x$ and $y$. Suppose that every iterated commutator with repeated generators is trivial; that is the following relation holds in $G$: $$[[x_{j_1},x_{j_2}]\cdots,x_{j_t}]=1$$ with $j_p=j_q$ for some $1\leq p<q\leq t$, where $x_{j_i}\in\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\},i=1,\cdots,t$.

Now I want to prove that for every $g\in G$ and $x_i\in S$, $$[x_i,[x_i,g]]=1\text{.}$$

---

My attempt:

Consider $[x_i,[x_i,g]]$ with $g=x_{j_1}^{\varepsilon_1}\cdots x_{j_t}^{\varepsilon_t}$, where $\varepsilon_k=\pm1$, $k=1,\cdots, t$. By [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039599/commutators-in-a-group), there exist elements $g_1,\cdots,g_t$ such that $$[x_i,g]=[x_i,x_{j_t}^{\varepsilon_t}]^{g_t}\cdots[x_i,x_{j_1}^{\varepsilon_1}]^{g_1}\text{.}$$Thus by [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039599/commutators-in-a-group) again, there exists elements $h_1\cdots, h_t\in G$ such that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
[x_i,[x_i,g]] &=&\ [x_i,[x_i,x_{j_t}^{\varepsilon_t}]^{g_t}\cdots[x_i,x_{j_1}^{\varepsilon_1}]^{g_1}]\\
&=&\ [x_i,[x_i,x_{j_1}^{\varepsilon_1}]^{g_1}]^{h_1}\cdots[x_i,[x_i,x_{j_t}^{\varepsilon_t}]^{g_t}]^{h_t}\\
&=&\ 1\text{,}\\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now I am having difficulty proving that each $[x_i,[x_i,x_{j_k}^{\varepsilon_k}]^{g_k}]=1$. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** I also thought about proving by induction on the "[length](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1038355/what-is-the-name-of-this-terminology)" of $g$, but am not sure how to proceed either.

Comment: Just keep expanding commutators of products as products of commutators using $[a,bc]=[a,c][c,[b,a]][a,b]$, and you will end up with a long product of iterated commutators, each of which contains two $x_i$s. I don't quite see yet how you deal with inverses of generators in the products. You probably need to use identities like $[a,b^{-1}] = [a,b]^{-b^{-1}}$.

Comment: @DerekHolt, thank you for the comment! For inverses I have proved that under the condition of the theorem, $[x_i,x_j^{-1}]=[x_i^{-1},x_j]=[x_i,x_j]^{-1}$. I still do not quite see how to write $[x_i,g]$ as a product of iterated commutators. The case that $g=x_jx_k$ is easy, but my difficulty is to prove the general case. Not sure how induction works here.

Comment: Why didn’t you simplify the stuff with $q = t$? Such commutation property entails all others with greater $t$ but the same $q$ .